# Macro functions to increment value of EXCEL cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Macro programming in Excel.

So far, I was able to create a program that turns

```
10.10.10.1
10.10.10.2
10.10.10.3
10.10.10.4
```

into

```
10.10.10.1
10.10.10.1
10.10.10.1
10.10.10.1
10.10.10.1
10.10.10.2
10.10.10.2
10.10.10.2
10.10.10.2
10.10.10.2
```

with the following:

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim RepeatFactor

    lRow = 1
    Do While (Cells(lRow, "A") <> "")

        RepeatFactor = 5
        If ((RepeatFactor > 1) And IsNumeric(RepeatFactor)) Then

           Range(Cells(lRow, "A"), Cells(lRow, "B")).Copy
           Range(Cells(lRow + 1, "A"), Cells(lRow + RepeatFactor - 1, "B")).Select
           Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown

           lRow = lRow + RepeatFactor - 1
        End If

        lRow = lRow + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

But now, I am trying to increment the third octet of each IP address up to a certain number, and then repeat.

Here is what I have:

[image]

And here is what I would like:

[image]

Please tell me what functions I should google ....

Comment: Is there a reason you cant just use +?  `value=value+1` `if value>14 then value=value-5`

Comment: I presented a simplified version of my problem. I am incrementing the third octet of about 1000 IP addresses, each scope has 16 addresses, and some most of the 3rd octets do not start with 0, they may start with 16, or 56, etc, etc .... hence the need to automate this

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you can't automate it using a simple incrementing function in vba.  Put it in a loop and when you hit the max value you want to increment to just reset the variable you are storing the 3rd octet in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a macro, this can be solved by using simply cell formulas (UDFs) and just copy them down.

```
A1 = 10
B1 = 10
C1 = 10+MOD(ROW(),4)
D1 = 0+INT(ROW()/4)
E1 = A1 & "." & B1 & "." & C1 & "." & D1
```

Then copy A1:E1 down....

(Note: Avoid macros! Macros are violating the functional character of a spreadsheet, intransparent (not visible how data is processed), often complicated (just try to read code from others), etc)

Comment: This was extremely helpful today!